# Как ограничить массивы символов для передачи в функцию

Tags: c, gdb

Есть константы:

```
const uint8_t background_part[5] = "\" & \"";
const uint8_t and_part[6] = "\" && \"";
const uint8_t output_to_start_part[5] = "\" > \"";
const uint8_t output_to_end_part[6] = "\" >> \"";
const uint8_t input_from_part[5] = "\" < \"";
const uint8_t bracket_left_part[5] = "\" ( \"";
const uint8_t bracket_right_part[5] = "\" ) \"";
```

Есть функция в другом модуле:

```
int32_t comp_last_copa_part (const copa *t, const uint8_t *buf, int32_t ssize_buf);
```

При передаче ей параметром buf консты background_part, например, в gdb отладчике происходит следующее:

```
comp_last_copa_part (t=0x55555555b2e0, buf=0x555555557093 <background_part> "\" & \"\" && \"\" > \"\" >> \"\" < \"\" ( \"\" ) \"Set termios new attributes", size_buf=5)
```

Вопрос: Почему передается такая строка? Что за buf=0x555555557093 <background_part> "" & "" && "" > "" >> "" < "" ( "" ) "Set termios new attributes"

"Set termios" это вообще строка из perror, вот фрагмент кода, он идет ниже объявлений констант:

```
} else {
        perror("Set termios new attributes");
        exit(1);
}
```

Я не знаю как четче назвать этот вопрос, если модераторы знают, то будьте добры поправить.

Я конечно вижу по коду, почему так получается, типа это начало всех ниже строк, но ведь это не правильно по-моему, как решаеются подобного рода проблемы?

Comment: Нуль терминированные строки.

Comment: Строковые литералы хранятся все в одном вместе, вы передаёте указатель на начало этого места и 5 байтов смещения, которые определяют конкретно `background_part`. Почему неправильно?

Comment: Смотрите, например, [адреса `0x402004` и `0x402009` для первых двух массивов](https://godbolt.org/z/6KaKn7z9d).

Comment: @tocic потому что в функию передается как массив всех строк друг за другом определенных...

Comment: @tocic мне нужно что бы отправилась параметром конкретно мной определенная строка, а оно всё остальное захватывает с собой. Смысл тогда всё определять вообще отдельно, если это то же самое для функции, что и создать один массив символов всех этих. Если смысл только в читабельности кода, то у меня слов нет.

Comment: В функцию передаётся только `0x555555557093` (см. [`mov    edi,0x402004`](https://godbolt.org/z/4Gh5nqMhs)), остальное `gdb` выводит для понимания.

Comment: @tocic нужно что бы передалось только 5 символов в функцию, а по обращению по адресу buf + 5 мне нужна ошибка, а не чтение другой константной области памяти определенной мной. Я просто так что ли размеры задал.

Comment: Так и есть, только по обращению `buf[5]` будет неопределённое поведение, необязательно рантайм ошибка.

Comment: Если вы передали в функцию размер массива, то не обращайтесь за пределы этого массива. Если вы хотите работать с массивом как со строками, то увеличьте размер массивов на единицу, чтобы влез символ `\0` и тогда будете работать как с нуль-терминированными строками.

Comment: @tocic спасибо )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как написал ori, размер ваших массивов не вмещает символ '\0' - конец строки. И в некоторых компиляторах выдается предупреждение - `initializer-string for array of chars is too long` "размер инициализирующей строки слишком велик". Просто сделайте все массивы на 1 больше, чем символов строках.

```
const uint8_t background_part[6] = "\" & \"";
```

Comment: В C это допустимо.

Comment: В С допустимо с точки зрения, что компилятор не дает ошибку. Но потом при передаче в функцию этот 0 отсутствует, и все строки склеиваются, что является ошибкой с точки зрения автора вопроса.

Comment: Понял, спасибо, исправлю. \0  и 0 ведь разные символы, конкретно \0 нужен ?

Comment: Он сам допишется, вам только место надо сделать для него. Его не видно, но он там есть. :) Но вообще-то это одно и то же либо '\0', либо просто 0.

Comment: 0 это 0x30 символ по ascii, а \0 это 0х0

Comment: Не символ 0. А целое значение 0. `char a = 0;` 0x0 как вы написали.

Comment: Понял, спасибо :)